# VSCode Omnisharp server A .NET 6 SDK for x86_64 was not found

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Omnisharp does not seem to recognize my installed .NET sdk (version 6.0.408).

I have tried manually adding this path via settings to Omnisharp: SDK path i.e.:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.403

I have also tried reinstalling the SDK and even VSCode.

This does not seem to solve the issue however, and I am unable to run my asp.net application on VSCode. Running dotnet run from the terminal is fine.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR: Both .NET SDK versions and Visual Studion versions needed to be x64.**

Here was the exact error I was seeing in the Output Window:

> [ERROR] A .NET 6 SDK for x86_64 was not found. Please install the
> latest x86_64 SDK from
> https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0.
>
> [ERROR] Error: OmniSharp server load timed out. Use the
> 'omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout' setting to override the default delay
> (one minute).

When I realized there was a mismatch between my .NET SDKs and Visual Studio Code in terms of being x86 and x64, I did the following:

1. Deleted the bin/obj folders and .vscode folders in my VS Code project.
2. Uninstalled my .NET SDKs via Windows (Setings > Apps).
3. Uninstalled Visual Studio Code  via Windows (Setings > Apps).
4. Installed .NET 7.0 x64 and .NET 6.0 x64.
5. Opened PowerShell and ran dotnet --info to make sure my .NET runtime and SDK were appearing correctly.
6. Installed Visual Studio Code x64.
7. Used PowerShell and cd'd to my project folder. Did a dotnet restore. Then launched Visual Studio Code using code . command.
8. I could then use the most current version of the VS Code extension (v1.25.2).

Answer (score 0):

You will also get this error if you are still running the 32-bit version of VS Code.  While I thought I had updated my machines with the 64-bit version, I never got around to updating one machine.  I uninstalled VS Code and reinstalled it, making sure I selected the 64-bit version.  This addressed the, *.NET 6 SDK for x86_64 was not found*, error.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and just solved it. Copy and pasting this from a Youtube comment I just finished writing, so it might sound funny out of context, but the good bits are in there. Hope it helps.

Installed dotnet 7.0, but then it said dotnet 6 was missing...
So I deleted the script asset, exited Unity, went back to their website and installed Net 6.0.403
Error still happened.

I'll note this seemed to push a script compiling error out to Unity in the inspector window, as well.

Deleted the script asset again, exited Unity again, then uninstalled both dotnet 7 and dotnet 6.
Then I reinstalled dotnet 6.

Into unity, made a new script, opened it, and this time no error message about missing net 6.

I just started yesterday. Literally. So if my solution is trash, I'll laugh with you lol. Best of luck.

Comment: You probably should post your own question/answer in another thread, as the original question here has nothing to do with Unity.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstalling and then installing the VSCode extension `C# for Visual Studio Code` solved the issue for me.